# Conditional subset of data frame by special condition

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements, subset

```
 df1 <-
 data.frame(Sector=c("auto","auto","auto","industry","industry","industry"),
 Topic=c("1","2","3","3","5","5"), 
 Frequency=c(1,2,5,2,3,2))
 df1

 df2 <- 
 data.frame(Sector=c("auto","auto","auto"),
 Topic=c("1","2","3"), 
 Frequency=c(1,2,5))
 df2
```

I have the dataframe 1 (df1) above and want a conditional subset of it that looks like df2. The condition is as followed:

"If at least one observation of the corresponding sectors has a larger frequency than 3 it should keep all observation of the sector, if not, all observations of the corresponding sector should be dropped."
In the example obove, only the three observations of the auto-sector remain, industry is dropped.

Has anybody an idea by which condition I might achieve the aimed subset?

Comment: `df1[df1$Sector %in% df1$Sector[df1$Frequency > 3],]`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `group_by` and `filter` from [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) to achieve this.

```
library(dplyr)

df2 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(Sector) %>%
  filter(any(Frequency > 3)) %>%
  ungroup()
df2
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#   Sector Topic Frequency
#   <fct>  <fct>     <dbl>
# 1 auto   1            1.
# 2 auto   2            2.
# 3 auto   3            5.
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with base `R`:

```
df1 <-
  data.frame(Sector=c("auto","auto","auto","industry","industry","industry"),
             Topic=c("1","2","3","3","5","5"), 
             Frequency=c(1,2,5,2,3,2))
subset(df1, ave(Frequency, Sector, FUN=max) >3)
```

and a solution with `data.table`:

```
library("data.table")
setDT(df1)[, if (max(Frequency)>3) .SD, by=Sector]
```